# Dynamically add an X number of divs to the right of prior divs and expand page horizontally (not vertically)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a "stock scroller" (marquee style). I'm fetching data from an API and want to display the logo along with the data (price and percentage change) in a full screen view, whereas the logo takes up 100% height of the page and the price and percentage change follows along it to the right.

The user can choose which and how many stocks to fetch the data for. Each subsequent stock (logo/data) should follow this pattern and be appended to the right of the previous/others.

There is a container `#anchorDiv` that houses all the data with these css attributes:

```
height:100vh;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Each stock(logo/data) is placed in a container of class type `.stockContainer` with these attributes:

```
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

The images within the container (`.stockContainer img`) have these attributes:

```
height: 96vh;
margin-top: 2vh;
margin-bottom: 2vh;
```

The text have these attributes:

```
float: right;
margin-right:5px;
color:black;
font-size:170px;
```

Here is the HTML code which exists inside the body:

```
<div id="anchorDiv">
        <div class="stockContainer">
            <img src="logos\aapl.png">
            <p class="percentChange">+20%</p>
            <p class="currentPrice">$20</p>
            <p class="stockName">AAPL</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stockContainer">
            <img src="logos\MSFT.png">
            <p class="percentChange">+20%</p>
            <p class="currentPrice">$20</p>
            <p class="stockName">MSFT</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Dynamically add more stockContainer divs here.. -->
    </div>
```

So although I have `white-space: nowrap` enabled, text still gets scrunched to the bottom below the images.
If I display the vertical overflow, I can see the text, if I hide the overflow I can't.

Basically, I want to dynamically continue to add content the right of the prior content (expand horizontally), but it keeps adding it either below or in weird places.

I am attaching images for clarity. This image represents what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

This image represents the results I'm currently getting:
[image]

```css
#anchorDiv {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.stockContainer img {
  height: 96vh;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

.stockContainer p {
  float: right;
  margin-right:5px;
  color:black;
  font-size:170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="anchorDiv">
        <div class="stockContainer">
            <img src="logos\aapl.png">
            <p class="percentChange">+20%</p>
            <p class="currentPrice">$20</p>
            <p class="stockName">AAPL</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stockContainer">
            <img src="logos\MSFT.png">
            <p class="percentChange">+20%</p>
            <p class="currentPrice">$20</p>
            <p class="stockName">MSFT</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Dynamically add more stockContainer divs here.. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide with the code: HTML and CSS (JS also) that you have written or you can create a minimal reproducible example which mimics the scenario. Try creating a code block for each code segment instead of inline code block as you have done previously.

Comment: make the example reproducible, otherwise it will be difficult to help you

Comment: I have tried to add more code and photos to adequately explain the problem. Could you please take another look?

Comment: I'll make you a reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

if i understood correctly, you want to add divs to container, and want them to stay along horizontal axis. You could use `display:flex`with `flex-wrap:nowrap`

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you use

```css
.containter{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Thus by formating content within the container as column based you create the boundry for the content of each stock. Or did I misinterpret the question?

Answer (score 0):

div elements has `display: block;` by default
so you can fix this by adding this to your styles

```
.stockContainer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```